# Why is my SQL search not working in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

Essentially, I've been doing SQL as a part of my Computer Science GCSE, and one task was to practice SQL in Python. Whilst doing so, I have hit a brick wall in the sense that the search for my program. It's been a real struggle trying to fix it, and I was hoping someone here could help me out. I've added in the full code. The main issue is that when I run it, it returns either `none` or just `[]`. Maybe someone is able to provide a cleaner answer. The criteria is to add records, update records, delete records and perform queries on the database through Python.

```
import sqlite3, os


def add():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE Movie_Collection(Name text, Released text, Genre text, Rating text)')

    c.execute('INSERT INTO Movie_Collection VALUES("Top Gun", "1986", "Action", "6.9")')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO Movie_Collection VALUES("Bee Movie", "2007", "Comedy", "6.1")')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO Movie_Collection VALUES("Hotel Rwanda", "2004", "Biography", "8.1")')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO Movie_Collection VALUES("Pirates of the Carribean: Curse of the Black Pearl", "2003", "Adventure", "8.0")')
    
    ndb.commit()


def input1():
    print('****MENU****')
    print('''Enter 1 to add record
Enter 2 to find item
Enter 3 to update records
Enter 4 to delete records
''')
    
    var = int(input('Enter number: '))
    print(' ')

    #adding
    if var == 1:
        name = str(input('Movie name: '))
        real = int(input('Release date: '))
        genre = str(input('Genre: '))
        rating = float(input('Rating: '))
        c.execute('INSERT INTO Movie_Collection VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', (name, real, genre, rating))
        ndb.commit()

    #searching
    elif var == 2:
        query_type = str(input('Query Type (name, release, genre, rating): '))
        
        if query_type.lower() == 'name':
            name_q =  input('Enter keyword: ')
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM Movie_Collection WHERE Name = ?', (name_q,))
            row = c.fetchall()
            print(row)
            ndb.commit()
                
        elif query_type.lower() == 'release':
            real_q = input('Enter keyword: ')
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM Movie_Collection WHERE Released = ?', (real_q,))
            row = c.fetchall()
            print(row)
            ndb.commit()
                
        elif query_type.lower() == 'genre':
            genre_q = str(input('Enter keyword: '))
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM Movie_Collection WHERE Genre = ?', (genre_q,))
            row = c.fetchall()
            print(row)
            ndb.commit()
                
        elif query_type.lower() == 'rating':
            rate_q = input('Enter keyword: ')
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM Movie_Collection WHERE Rating = ?', (rate_q,))
            row = c.fetchall()
            print(row)
            ndb.commit()

    #Updating
    elif var == 3:
        record_q1 = str(input('Enter the name of the record you would like to update: '))
        print('''1. Release date
2. Genre
3. Rating
''')
        record_q2 = int(input('What field do you want to update? (1, 2 or 3) '))
        if record_q2 == 1:
            new_date = input('Enter a new release date: ')
            c.execute('UPDATE Movie_Collection SET Released = ? WHERE Name = ?', (new_date, record_q1))
            ndb.commit()
        elif record_q2 == 2:
            new_genre = input('Enter a new genre: ')
            c.execute('UPDATE Movie_Collection SET Genre = ? WHERE Name = ?', (new_genre, record_q1))
            ndb.commit()
        elif record_q2 == 3:
            new_rating = input('Enter a new rating: ')
            c.execute('UPDATE Movie_Collection SET Rating = ? WHERE Name = ?', (new_rating, record_q1))
            ndb.commit()
        

    #Deleting
    elif var == 4:
        record_q3 = input('Enter the name of the record you would like to delete: ')
        c.execute('DELETE FROM Movie_Collection WHERE Name = ?', (record_q3,))
        ndb.commit()


if not os.path.isfile('MoviesCollections.db'):
    ndb = sqlite3.connect('MovieCollections.db')
    c = ndb.cursor()

    add()
    run = True
    while run == True:
        input1()
        print(' ')
        ask = str(input('Do u want to continue? '))
        if ask.lower() == 'n' or ask.lower() == 'no':
            run = False
        else:
            run = True
        print(' ')
    ndb.commit()
    ndb.close()
```

[This is what happens when I run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4rct.png)
[Even though the records are there without adjustment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXd6o.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what "it" is in "`it returns either none or just []`", and what "it" is returning? Are you able to make a [mre] with just a few lines of code that still demonstrates the same issue? If you did that it would be super helpful.

Comment: So if you directly run a query like `SELECT * FROM Movie_Collection WHERE Name = "whatever"` on the database, it returns data, but it's not returning data when run from within Python?

Comment: Yep, when I run that `SELECT * FROM Movie_Collection WHERE Name = "Top Gun"` and this it returns `["Top Gun", "1986", "Action", "6.9"` as it should

Comment: If you just plug that command straight into Python with the name hardcoded, does it return anything?

Comment: yes, it does. My teacher can't seem to figure it out either. It seems to be just the name query and genre query, which are both text, but the other fields are the text aswell

Comment: Maybe you could try making a very tiny program that just tries to fetch the data you want, and see if it still is messed up? Maybe try just modifying some existing example code online that for sure should work. Another suggestion is seeing what exactly is in `name_q` and such. It could be that for some reason it's not the string you think it is. IDK at this point.